# Changing the labels on ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, gradient, legend

I'm using ggplot so I can get a gradient onto a map to show data over a large scale. There are points between 0 and 35,000 to be visualised. I have got this to work, but the legend is automatically showing labels for every 10,000.

[image: Current legend]

Ideally I want the legend to show the maximum amount, so probably it would just show 0 at the bottom and 35,000 at the top. Is this doable?

My ggplot code is below if this helps.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = datafile, aes(map_id = Health_Board, fill = datafile$"2007"), map = Scot) +
  geom_polygon(data = Scot, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "gray", fill = NA) +
  expand_limits(x = Scot$long, y = Scot$lat) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = ("lightyellow"), high = ("red"), limits = c(0,35000)) +
  ggtitle("2007") +
  coord_fixed(1.2) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
    axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899454/editing-legend-labels-in-ggplot?rq=1)?

Comment: Thanks. Marco, I am using scale_fill_gradient at the moment. If I use scale_fill_gradientn, which argument will allow me to adapt the legend like this?

Comment: `labels` argument in `scale_fill_gradientn` would help you. If you post the reproducible example, someone could help you with the detailed solution.

Comment: Setting `breaks = c(0, 35000)` inside `scale_fill_gradient` should work

Comment: @MarcoSandri I'm not understanding your suggestion?  Why that over what the poster is using?

Comment: Thanks, Tyler, the breaks argument was exactly right - I had started playing around with that but I didn't have the c so it didn't work properly until you commented! The one problem is that then the top label is squashed up against the title. I can't see an argument for the position of the legend title to try shift it up or away a bit. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include the "breaks" argument. Like this:

```
scale_fill_gradient(low = ("lightyellow"), high = ("red"),
                        breaks=c(min(lat),max(lat)),
                        limits = c(0,35000)) +
```

If you want more, its possible to include the "labels" argument.

```
scale_fill_gradient(low = ("lightyellow"), high = ("red"),
                        breaks=c(min(lat),max(lat)),
                        labels=c("Minimum","Maximum"),
                        limits = c(0,35000)) +
```